# Android several Web Service Calls on load

Tags: java, android, multithreading, web-services, sqlite

I have been learning Android for the past 3 months or so. However, I haven't come across anything like this yet.

I want to access several different web services when the application is initially loaded.  The response from these web services should go into the DB for retrieval where needed in the application.  I have a splash screen from which I am attempting to do this:

```
public class SplashScreen extends BaseActivity {

    protected static final int SPLASH_DURATION = 2000;

    protected ContactInfoRetriever contactInfoRetriever = new ContactInfoRetriever();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    startSplashThread();
    }

    private void startSplashThread() {
    Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
            try {
            Looper.prepare();
            // fire off the calls to the different web services.
            updateContactInfo();
            updateFooInfo();
            updateBarInfo();

            int waited = 0;
            while (waited < SPLASH_DURATION) {
                sleep(100);
                waited += 100;
            }                   
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(SplashScreen.class.getSimpleName(), "The splash thread was interrupted.");
            }
            finally {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LandingPageActivity.class));
            }
        }

        };
    splashThread.start();
    }

    protected void updateContactInfo() {

    PerformContactInfoSearchTask task = new PerformContactInfoSearchTask();
    task.execute();
    }    

    protected void updateFooInfo() {
    PerformFooTask task = new PerformFooTask();
    task.execute();
    }

    protected void updateBarInfo() {
    PerformBarTask task = new PerformBarTask();
    task.execute();
    }

    private class PerformContactInfoSearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ContactInfo> {


    @Override
        protected ContactInfo doInBackground(String... params) {
        // this calls a class which calls a web service, and is then passed to an XML parser.
        // the result is a ContactInfo object
        return contactInfoRetriever.retrieve();
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final ContactInfo result) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
            InsuranceDB db = new InsuranceDB(SplashScreen.this);
            // insert the ContactInfo into the DB
            db.insertContactInfo(result);
            }
        });
    }

    }   

    private class PerformFooTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FooInfo> {
    // similar to the PerformContactInfoSearchTask
    }

    private class PerformBarTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, BarInfo> {
    // similar to the PerformContactInfoSearchTask
    }

}
```

I haven't been successful with this yet.  What is the best way to do this?  I don't need to update the UI thread when the tasks are completed.  Does this mean I should be using something other than `AsyncTask`?  I read something about a Looper and Handler.  Is this the correct thing to use?  Any code samples would be wonderful.

Thanks,
Zack

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have a race condition in that the web service calls are not completed before the wait period has ended and the activity is finished.

A better approach may be to:

- remove the waiting, finish(), and
  startActivity() from the splash
  thread.
- combine all the web service
  calls into on AsyncTask.
- move all the db operations to the
  task's doInBackground method.
- in the task's onPostExecuteMethod, do
  your finish and startActivity().

Comment: That sounds good.  However, they only want the splash screen to show up for 2 seconds. Any other loading past that should just keep happening in the background.  I have moved away from using AsyncTask at all and just creating regular Threads.  This seems to be working better, since AsyncTask's function is to allow a background thread to interact with the UI thread.